# MVC: Reverse ajax called table to original partial view

Tags: model-view-controller

On the website I have two partial views rendering 2 tables,one on the left and one right. On the left hand table I have an Action-Link to call an ajax function which will render and replace the table on the right hand side.

Now here is the question:

The table is being replaced on the right. How can I revert to the original table on a button click ?. I do not want to use database queries to achieve this but rather find a better way. 
Thank you for your time, I would appreciate if anyone could help me answer this.

Here is the ajax code used:

```
    @section scripts
        {
        <script>
         function productVersionCustomers(id) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetCustomersFromVersionID")',
                data: { id: id },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#versionCustomers').html(data);`enter code here`
                    TableManaged.init();
                }
            });enter code here
          };
         </script>
    }
```

Comment: found a solution for it !! To reload page through browser cache 

<input type="button" value="Reload Page" onClick="history.go(0)">

Comment: For more info to my answer http://www.dotnetbull.com/2011/08/refreshing-or-reloading-page-through.html